# Why json is parsed diffrently on diffrent application environments?

Tags: javascript, java, json, tomcat, glassfish

I have json object in java, which I return to browser using obj.toString(). `response.setContentType("application/json")` is setting return type to json. 
example:

```
obj = {
name: "pp",
age: 24
}
```

Application on tomcat: response received is

```
obj = {
name: "pp",
age: 24
}
```

but Application on glassfish: response received is

```
obj = {
name: "pp",
age: "24"
}
```

Notice that age is treated as string which is causing lot of problem.
Above is just an dummy json, I am having huge json with lot of key's and values and most of the values are Integer or floats. So How Can i get json in which data type of values are preserved.

Comment: `How Can i get json in which has data type of values are preserved` - don't use glassfish?

Comment: Which library ur using for jsonization ?

Answer (score 0):

In application as it is very old appication initialy we used xml response. While upgrading the sytem we went for json response. To reduce code change, we just converted the xml to json using function in json.jar.

```
JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(returnStrXML);
```

Problem was here while converting xml to json. In my environment i had diffrent jar which smartly converted xml in json perserving its data types. While the json.jar converts all the values to string by default. Changing the jar solved the problem.